# Подключение к API Яндекс.Метрики, проблемы с токеном

Tags: python, яндекс-метрика

Подключаюсь к API Яндекс.Метрики. При подключении всегда отдает 403 ошибку.
Как будто проблема с токеном.

1. Приложение создал

[image: Мое приложение]

2. Доступ у приложения к метрике есть
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Счетчик у меня в управлении: 50766676
4. Скрипт на тестовом счетчике отрабатывает и если я сделаю счетчик публичным -тоже

   ```
   import requests
   import sys

   header = {'Authorization': 'AQAAAAAAlc93AAWFfpGrC1vQA0KggaP3zz91QDw'}
   ids = {
       'Count_1': 50766676,
   }

   payload = {
       'metrics': 'ym:s:pageviews, ym:s:users',
       'date1': '2019-02-01',
       'date2': '2019-02-27',
       'filters': "ym:s:deviceCategory!='mobile'",
       'ids': 50766676,
       'accuracy': 'full',
       'pretty': True,
   }

   i = 1
   for key, value in ids.items():
       payload['ids'] = value
       r = requests.get('https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data', params=payload, headers=header)
       data = str(r.json()['max'])[1:-1].split(",")
       i += 1
       payload['ids'] = value
       print('total', key, data)
   ```

Помогите понять ошибку. Все данные оставляю открытыими.

Comment: Ваш код у меня отдает статус 200 и результат 
`total Count_1 ['671.0', ' 485.0']`

Comment: Можете еще раз проверить, пожалуйста. Я закрыл доступ к счетчику публичный.

Comment: Теперь `{'errors': [{'error_type': 'access_denied', 'message': 'Access is denied'}], 'code': 403, 'message': 'Access is denied'}`

Comment: Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой. Предложенный вариант с header = {'Authorization': 'OAuth AQAAAAAAlc93AAWFfpGrC1vQA0KggaP3zz91QDw'} как и header = {'Authorization': 'AQAAAAAAlc93AAWFfpGrC1vQA0KggaP3zz91QDw'}
не работает. Все равно отдает 403 ошибку. Поделитесь удалось ли решить проблему?

Answer (score 3):

Если проблема в том, что получаете ошибку 403, когда к счетчику нет публичного доступа, обратите внимание на вот эту строчку в настройках, указанных на яндекс.метрике

Authorization: ***OAuth*** 05dd3dd84ff948fdae2bc4fb91f13e22bb1f289ceef0037

соответственно у Вас header = {} должен иметь вид

header = {'Authorization': 'OAuth AQAAAAAAlc93AAWFfpGrC1vQA0KggaP3zz91QDw'}

Вот ответ от Вашего счетчика после исправления header

total Count_1 ['672.0', ' 485.0']