# Проблемы с подключением к API Яндекс.Метрики

Tags: php, yandex-metrika-api

1. Создал приложение: 
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. дал ему доступы: 
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. получил токен здесь https://tech.yandex.ru/oauth/doc/dg/tasks/get-oauth-token-docpage/.

4.Хочу получить отчет:

```
$url = 'https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data';
$oauth_token = 'AQAAAAAERkkuAAWm1kmj8FEypEKkriccnX3eOJE';

$headers = [
   'Host' =>  'api-metrika.yandex.net',
   'Authorization' => 'OAuth ' . $oauth_token,
   'Content-Type' =>  'application/x-yametrika+json',
   'Content-Length'  => '123'
];

$params = [
    'ids'         => '38087760',
    'metrics'     => 'ym:s:visits,ym:s:pageviews,ym:s:users',
    'dimensions'  => 'ym:s:date',
    'date1'       => '7daysAgo',
    'date2'       => 'yesterday',
    'sort'        => 'ym:s:date',
];
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);

$page = curl_exec ($ch);
if ($page === FALSE) {
    echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch); 
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($page); 
echo '</pre>';
```

5.А получаю Access denied.

```
{"errors":[{"error_type":"access_denied","message":"Access is denied"}],"code":403,"message":"Access is denied"}"
```

Не могу понять почему нет доступа.

Comment: Не указывайте в заголовках Host и Content-Length, может заработает

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подключение к API Яндекс.Метрики, проблемы с токеном](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950123/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba-api-%d0%af%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc)

Answer (score 0):

У самого была такая проблема, почему-то через Curl не работает, надо через file_get_contents. Вот так будет в Вашем случае:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
     'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Authorization: OAuth AQAAAAAERkkuAAWm1kmj8FEypEKkriccnX3eOJE'.PHP_EOL.
                    'Content-Type: application/x-yametrika+json' . PHP_EOL
      ),
));

$url = 'https://api-metrika.yandex.ru/stat/v1/data';
$params = array(
    'ids'         => '38087760',
    'metrics'     => 'ym:s:visits,ym:s:pageviews,ym:s:users',
    'dimensions'  => 'ym:s:date',
    'date1'       => '7daysAgo',
    'date2'       => 'yesterday',
    'sort'        => 'ym:s:date',
)
$page = json_decode(file_get_contents( $url . '?' . http_build_query($params), false, $context), true);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($page); 
echo '</pre>'
```